# What makes dynamic_rnn faster to compile?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a complicated network with many repeated RNN steps. Compiling takes a long time (30+ minutes, mostly stuck at the gradient step) and I found that [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/511) might be related, which mentions [dynamic_rnn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L690) as a much faster way to compile:

Looking over dynamic_rnn, I then reformatted my network to include a while_loop, like so:

```
#input: tensor with 1000 time steps
def body(i, prev_state):
    inp = tf.slice(input, i, 1)
    new_state = cell(tf.squeeze(int), prev_state) # Includes scope reuse
    return [tf.add(i, tf.constant(1)), new_state]

def cond(i):
    return some_cond(i)

tf.while_loop(cond, body, [tf.constant(0), initial_state])
```

But this didn't seem to help. What besides simply putting the cell call in a loop makes dynamic_rnn so much faster to compile?